# Spanish characters in Android Studio

Tags: encoding, android-studio, iso, utf

I've got a problem with Android Estudio, i'm trying to develope an application but the characters like "¿" or "ñ" and "á,é,ó,í,ú" don't appear correctly when i run the application. I've tried to solve the problem changing the encoding to UTF-8 but it doesn't matter nothing different. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this problem by using Unicode Characters:

http://javawiki.sowas.com/doku.php?id=java:unicode

Just replace the Number by the respective char you need:

http://unicode-table.com/de/#0115

For Example:

```
¿ = \u00BF
ñ = \u0148 
á = \u0227
é = \u00E9
```

Hope this is what u needed ;)

Answer (score 5):

Instead of having to replace every accent with Unicode character to comply with the project setting of UTF-8, just simply add this line to the Module App Build Grade within android node:

android {

```
compileOptions.encoding "ISO-8859-1" // For Spanish [Otherwise strange accents]
```

Then you don't have to modify any of the existing data that you have written and you can keep those strange Spanish characters!

Comment: your solution doesn't work for me. I have the same issue using french accents.

Comment: perfect! works for all latin languages; see wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Answer (score 2):

Hey I got the solution

> String strJunk = "AtrÃ©vete a SoÃ±ar";
>
> byte[] arrByteForSpanish = strJunk.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
>
> String strSpanish = new String(arrByteForSpanish);

I did this and now I am getting Spanish characters correctly instead of junk characters.

Comment: it helped me when the string is coming from the server.

Answer (score 0):

in bild.gradle(app model) 
use this configuration:

```
android {
compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1' // write your encoding here
compileSdkVersion 25...
```